# Int to Date conversion error without any changes happening in data model in Talend

Tags: talend

I had the ETL working until two days ago when I started receiving:

> Exception in component tDBInput_1 (test4) java.sql.SQLDataException:
>   Unsupported conversion from TIMESTAMP to java.lang.Integer

Clueless what happened here.

Comment: Maybe you database column type is a timestamp and your DB schema in the component is an integer. Can we have more detail like screen of your schema and components

Comment: @ThéoCapdet, just updated. Thank you for looking into it. I already peeled my eyes and don't understand what's going on.

Comment: Its in the tdbinput component not the output

Comment: @ThéoCapdet,but is not the left-part of the image uploaded an input table?

Comment: No It's the link "out1" in input here

Comment: Check the schema of the component named tDBInput_1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like your schema in your tDb_Input_1 is not the same between schema inside component and your database table type. For exemple product_line_id is a varchar in your table and it's a Integer in your schema.

Try to redefine your schema in yout tDBInput Component.

You can do it like that :

- Define your DB connection inside metadata (in Db Connection)
- Retrieve schema from your database in order to import the schema automatically in Talend. (See screeshot)
- Use the schema retrieved in your component and propagate to all the job.

[image]

Comment: just as add, another often reason - order of columns, the schema could be defined properly, but in the query, columns reordered or excluded